# Semaphores and Thread Synchronization

Tags: producer-consumer, dining-philosopher

I've been trying to learn about semaphores and thread synchronization by going through some classical problems like producer-consumer problem and dining philosopher's problem.

While reading the solutions of the above problems implemented in C, I've stumbled upon this piece of code segment present in both the solutions

```
pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
```

So as far as I know,

> Semaphores are implemented so that only one process can access a part
> of the program, at a given time

But `pthread_join` does the same thing, isn't it? It delays the execution of a thread until the other thread has finished execution.

So why add this function even though semaphores are implemented?

Comment: 'join' is the opposite of 'fork' -- the caller is waiting for another thread to terminate.   You could use an explicit semaphore, but then the terminating thread must be sure to 'up' the semaphore before exit, something for a failing thread to guarantee, unless you made it part of the kernel thread termination code.  But then you'd probably want a call to wait on the kernel's semaphore.  You could name that call 'join' :-)

Comment: To shorten my previous comment: 'join' is a very specific operation and thus benefits from being explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but why should I use join even if I'm using semaphores?

Comment: You use join when you want to wait for a thread to terminate. It's the simple, straightforward, and effective solution that gives an unambiguous determination that the thread has terminated.  There are many ways you could write code to achieve the same effect, but really, why not use the one method that's actually designed for awaiting thread termination?  This advice of course only applies to the case that termination is what you're interested in; in (say) the typical producer/consumer scenario, you're not awaiting termination.

Comment: So is join redundant?

Comment: No.  Read what I wrote.

Comment: So without join no output is obtained, why's that?

Comment: What output?  No output was mentioned.  But buffered I/O needs to be flushed, which may be taken care of by thread exit automatically, but not by V'ing a semaphore.